# If sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ on $X$, show that if $\mathcal{B}$ is finite, it must be generated by a finite partition of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> If sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ on $X$, show that if $\mathcal{B}$ is finite, it must be generated by a finite partition $\{P_1,...,P_n\}$of $X$.

Can I assume $\mathcal{B}=\{A_1,...,A_n\}$ and then prove $\{A_1,...,A_n\}=\sigma(P_1,...,P_n)$?

If this not correct, could you give me some hint?

Comment: Note that if $\{ P_1, \ldots, P_n \}$ is a partition of $X$ then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ has $2^n$ elements, not just $n$.

Comment: @So could you give me some hint about this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal B =\{A_1,A_2,...,A_n\}$. Consider the collection of all sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2\cap...\cap B_n$ where each $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or $A_i^{c}$. Show that this is  partition and each $A_i$ is a union of some members of this partition. Then conclude that this partition generates $\mathcal B$.

Comment: It may help to try this out for $n=2$.

Comment: It is easy to show $B_1\cap B_2$ are disjoint when $n=2$. But how about the $n$?

Comment: If you take any two such intersections there will be some $i$ where $B_i=A_i$ in one and $B_i=A_i^{c}$ in the other. So the intersection is empty. @LoveQYG

Comment: My answer was wrong..glad you accepted this answer..+1 also from me..:)

Comment: @MariosGretsas Where is the wrong?

Comment: I wrote that $B_j=A_j \cap A_{j-1}$...but the $A_j's $ are disjoint...i know an intutitve proof of what you ask but it does not matter since it has been already answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the *atoms*: an element $P$ of a Boolean algebra is an atom, if $P\ne0$ and $Q\le P\implies (Q=0\lor Q=P)$.

Comment: Do you mean $B_1\cap...\cap B_n$?

Comment: What are $B_i$? All the elements? Then their intersection is the empty set. An atom here is a minimal nonempty element of $\mathcal B$.